# Make Url friendly from string

Tags: javascript

For example I have this string:

```
make no@ sen# `se !
```

I would to generate url like this

```
make-no-sen-se!
```

I have this:

```
    var value = $('.titleVal').val();
    if (value != '') {
        value = value.replace(/[^a-z0-9 _-]/gi, '-').toLowerCase();

        value = value.split(' ');
        var result = '';

        for (var i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
            if ((value.length - 1) == i) {
                result += value[i];
            } else {
                result += value[i] + '-';
            }
        }
        $('#vidUrl').val(result);
    }
```

But it generate this:

```
make-no--sen---se--
```

Comment: Maybe just follow that with a regex that collapses multiples of `-` to just one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `+` or `*` to represent repeated occurance of a set.

```
function process(value) {
    return value == undefined ? '' : value.replace(/[^a-z0-9_]+/gi, '-').replace(/^-|-$/g, '').toLowerCase();
}

var result = process($('.titleVal').val());
$('#vidUrl').val(result);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
value = value.replace(/[^a-z0-9 _-]/gi, '-').toLowerCase();
```

should probably be

```
value = encodeURIComponent(value.toLowerCase().replace(/[^a-z0-9 _-]+/gi, '-'));
```

Calling `toLowerCase` before doing the replace will make sure that Latin upper-case letters are not replaced with dashes.

The '+' after the character set will convert sequences of multiple characters like '@ ' to a single dash.

The `encodeURIComponent` call will ensure that the result is safe to include in a URL path component.

You might also want to look into [expanding the set of letters and digits that you do not replace with dashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280712/javascript-unicode) so that the result is more friendly to non-Western-European users.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
var value = "-make no@ sen# `se !";
if (value != "") {
    value = value.replace(/[^a-z0-9]/g, '-')
                 .replace(/\-{2,}/g, '-')
                 .toLowerCase();
    if(value.indexOf("-", 1) != -1)
        value = value.substring(1);

    if(value.indexOf("-", value.length -1) != -1)
        value = value.substring(0,value.length - 1);

    console.log(value);
}
```